# Standing for kaddish

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, kaddish

Most of the siddurim by Chacham Ovadia Yosef זצ"ל say to stand at the khatzi kaddish of Shabbat Arvit right before Kryat Shema. I have heard that this minhag is from the Ben Ish Chai (I don't exactly know which place). Is this minhag followed by all sefardim all around the world?  Also, where is the exact location of the minhag in the Ben Ish Chai and also which other poskim write about it?

Comment: I can't vouch for specifically this Kaddish or Sephardi minhag. However, I think Shulchan Aruch mentions a minhag to stand for *every* kaddish. This is learned from the story of *Ehud* who when he was about to kill the king, said, "I have an important word from G-d" and the king rose from his seat.

Comment: Source is in one of the answers, below. It was Eglon who stood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sepharadim are lenient to sit for Kaddish in general. However, on Leil Shabbat the Mekubalim have a chumra to stand for Barechu and, by extension, Kaddish. The *Ruach* of Kedushat Shabbat is accepted with Barechu, so one should stand to accept it. Once one is already standing for Barechu, the Minhag developed to stand for Kaddish as well.

**Ben Ish Chai Shannah Sheniah Parashat Vayera 3**

> ג. בליל שבת יש לאדם שלשה מיני תוספת שבת, הא' תוספת נפש, וזה נעשה בעת קבלת שבת באומרו באי כלה, והב' תוספת הרוח, וזה נעשה בעת שאומרים ברכו קודם ערבית, והג' תוספת הנשמה, וזה נעשה בעת שאומרים ופרוס עלינו ועל ירושלים עירך סוכת רחמים ושלום, ואלו הם בחינת הלילה של שבת, דהיינו שהם מצד המלכות שזמן עלייתה הוא בליל שבת, אך ביום שבת יש עוד ג' מיני תוספת של בחינת היום, והם יותר מעולין שהוא מצד התפארת שהוא יותר עליון שה"ס דוכרא. ושלשה אלו נבארם לקמן בשבת הבאה בע"ה. ולכן בעת קבלת שבת באומרך בואי כלה וכו' שהוא עיקר קבלת שבת, תכוין לקבל תוספת הנפש, **ובאמירת ברכו תכוין לקבל תוספת הרוח, ומפורש בסידור רבינו הרש"ש שקבלת תוספת הרוח תהיה בעניית ברכו, דהיינו כאשר עונה ואומר ברוך ה' המבורך לעולם ועד יע"ש. ומ"מ מעת שאומר בעל הקדיש ברכו את ה' המבורך, יכוין השומע להכין עצמו לקבלה זו, וכן זה האומר הקדיש עצמו ג"כ עיקר קבלת הרוח אצלו כשאומר ברוך ה' המבורך. וכתבו בשם רבינו מהרח"ו ז"ל, שצריך האדם להיות עומד בקדיש ברכו כדי לקבל תוספת הרוח מעומד,** וכן צריך לקום כשאומר ופרוס כדי לקבל תוספת הנשמה מעומד, ונמצא שאם לא יתפלל בציבור, דאינו שומע ברכו ועונה, הנה הוא מפסיד קבלה זו...

**Yalkut Yosef 56:11**

> יא. כשאומר השליח צבור קדיש, אין הקהל חייבים לעמוד, כדי לענות אמן יהא שמיה רבא מעומד, אלא רשאים לענות אמן יהא שמיה רבא כשהם יושבים. וכן המנהג פשוט אצל הספרדים ועדות המזרח, ומנהגינו מיוסד על פי דעת רבינו האר"י ז"ל וגדולי האחרונים. ורק מי שהיה עומד והתחילו לומר קדיש כשהוא עומד, לא ישב עד שיענה אמן יהא שמיה רבא עד דאמירן בעלמא, ואחר כך ישב. וכן אם עמד בקדיש מלא קומתו לכבוד תלמיד חכם או זקן, ישאר עומד עד שיסים לענות אמן יהא שמיה רבא, ואחר כך ישב. וכל זה כשקם מלא קומתו, [כגון שקם מפני שיבה], אבל אם קם בהידור בעלמא, אין צריך לעמוד כדי לענות. והרואה את חבירו שבא לישב באמצע הקדיש, נכון שיזכירנו שצריך לעמוד עד שיסיים עניית יהא שמיה רבא. וכן נוהגים על פי הקבלה לעמוד בשעת אמירת קדיש וברכו שלפני תפלת ערבית של ליל שבת, כדי לקבל שבת בתוספת הרוח. ומנהג האשכנזים כדעת הרמ"א, לעמוד בשעה שעונים קדיש וברכו, וספרדי שמתפלל עם אשכנזים, נכון שיעמוד גם הוא עמהם בעת אמירת קדיש וברכו, כדי שלא יהיה בכלל יושב בין העומדים.יא)

Answer (score 2):

If one is already standing (for instance, for Barechu), it is forbidden to sit down for the subsequent Kaddish. One may sit for Kaddish -- according to Sephardic practice -- only if one was already seated.

Source: Ben Ish Hai, Vayehi 8:

ספר בן איש חי - הלכות שנה ראשונה - פרשת ויחי 
[ח] קדיש שתפסו מעומד, כגון קדיש שאחר העמידה ואחר ההלל, שהיה עומד בתחילתו, ישאר עומד עד אחר ענית אמן יהא שמיה רבא כולה, וכן יש ליזהר בכל הקדישים שמזדמן שהוא היה יושב כשהתחילו בקדיש, ועבר זקן או תלמיד חכם, וקם מפניהם, שישאר עומד, עד אחר עניית אמן יהא שמיה רבא, מאחר שכבר עמד חשיב

This ruling is quoted in Siddur Ohd Yosef Hai p. 92, "Hanhagot beKaddish" article 3.

The reason for standing during this particular Barechu was already adequately explained.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.schechter.edu/should-we-stand-or-sit-for-the-kaddish/) is a wonderful piece on the general topic of standing or sitting during Kaddish, it is well organized and inclusive of the pro, anti and parve shitos and he points out the issues with the Rama in Darkhai Moshe to the Tur(OH 56,3) namely
a) it is not in the Mordechai he quotes;
b) it is not in the Yerushalmi he brings down;
c) the passuk quoted is not in Tanach

http://www.schechter.edu/should-we-stand-or-sit-for-the-kaddish/

Answer (score 0):

Shulchan Aruch (Maran of the Sefaradim) Orach Chaim 56,1 Folowing the Hagahot Maimoni and Talmid Yerushalmi:

> ויש לעמוד כשעונין קדיש וכל דבר שבקדושה
>   One should stand when answering Kaddish and Kedusha

The Mishna brura bring 2 opinions when one needs to stand.

> עד אחר שיסיים איש"ר וי"א שיש לעמוד עד אמן שלאחר יתברך וכו' ואמרו אמן:
>   1.One should stand until completing *Amen Yehe Shemei Raba Mevorch Leolam Uleolmei Olmaya*
>   2.One should stand till the end of *Daamiran Bealma Veimru amen*

Note The Darkei Moshe in the name of the Maharil (ashkenazi Posek) says:

> בד"מ כתב שמהרי"ל לא היה קם אך כל קדיש שתפסו מעומד
>   One only needs to stand for Kaddish if one is already standing I.e don't sit down but one can remain seated

But the Mishna Brura strongly advises to keep with Maran's ruling to stand during Kadish:
.ויש ללמוד ק"ו מעגלון מלך מואב שהיה נכרי וקם מעצמו מעל כסאו לדבר ד' כ"ש אנחנו
If Eglon King of Moav stood from his throne (who was not Jewish) when he Heard the name of Hashem, how much more so ourselves!

Comment: This is irrelevant to his question. He's referring to a Minhag to stand for Kaddish (which is just agav standing for the Barechu which accepts the Ruach of Kedushat Shabbat.

Comment: Actually @mdjava look in the comments to the question and you will see that the questioner was also interested in knowing about standing for kaddish in general. But feel free to down item even though this answer clearly indicates one should stand up for any Kaddish including before Borchu

Comment: There are two different issues. Sepharadim are lenient to sit for Kaddish in general. However, on Leil Shabbat the Mekubalim have a chumra to stand for Barechu and, by extension, Kaddish. That's the note in the siddur the questioner is referring to.